# HTTP Status 404 Spring MVC

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I've read many questions which are similar to mine, but I haven't found the solution. I created this project in eclipse and it was working properly. Afterwards, I uploaded it to github, deleted it from my PC. Later, I cloned it from github to my PC, and I used "import existing maven project" and that loaded the project in eclipse. But when I run it now I get the following error (I added the project into tomcat server):

```
HTTP Status 404 - /springProject/
type Status report

message /springProject/

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
```

Here are my codes:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>springProject</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>springProject.springProject</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

MvcConfiguration.java

```
package springProject.springProject.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="springProject.springProject")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


}
```

HomeController.java

```
package springProject.springProject.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the name that you deploy this application to tomcat as? The error message suggests that it should be `springProject`. Note that Tomcat also honors capital letters - so it should be in tomcat's `webapps/springProject` if you haven't used another deployment technique. If you've deployed through eclipse (as you're tagging this question with eclipse), just make sure that this is the name of your project, and the name that's shown in the "Server" view.

Also, check tomcat's logs for any problems - e.g. there might have been a deployment problem that prohibits you seeing this project.

Comment: The project was saved with the correct name, but the problem was that the tomcat server in Eclipse was already run when I imported the new project from github. When I restarted the tomcat server the error disapeared.